# Importing csv files as numpy compatible list of lists in python

Tags: python, csv, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I'm attempting to import a .csv file into my IPython notebook using the following:

```
import csv
datafile_dC = open('/Users/iMacHome/dual-Core.csv', 'r')
datareader_dC = csv.reader(datafile_dC)
data_dC = []
for row in datareader_dC:
data_dC.append(row)

data_dC = np.array(data_dC)
print data_dC

x = data_dC[:, 6]
y = data_dC[:, 7]
```

Printing the data yields (shorthand):

```
[['1.29940' '-0.06908' '0.85295' ..., '-0.83824' '-0.11374' '0.11374']
 ['0.93471' '0.10030' '1.25981' ..., '-1.47697' '0.02932' '-0.02932']
 ['0.57901' '0.25031' '1.77954' ..., '-1.28751' '0.23731' '-0.23731']
 ..., 
 ['1.26506' '-0.21818' '0.60509' ..., '-1.15941' '-0.10211' '0.10211']
 ['1.22592' '-0.39114' '0.40631' ..., '-1.71412' '-0.08846' '0.08846']
 ['2.13359' '-0.51551' '0.30513' ..., '-2.07729' '-0.32911' '0.32911']]
```

However, using this method* seems to yield the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'numpy.ndarray'
```

when calling the following:

```
def myBoundary(x, y0=-2.163, slope=-1.7):
    return (slope * x) + y0

y_boundary = myBoundary(x, y0=-2.163, slope=-1.7)
```

I know this is quite trivial but if anyone could suggest a way of solving this problem I would be very grateful.

**N.B.** *Manually entering the data as a list of lists doesn't yield the same error.

Comment: You should cast your data to float numbers and actually convert the list of lists to a numpy list.

Comment: How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Are you aware of `loadtxt` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) and `genfromtxt` (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def myBoundary(x, y0=-2.163, slope=-1.7):
    x = np.array([float(x0) for x0 in x])
    return (slope * x) + y0
```

Your data was a list of string

Comment: The length of y_boundary is the same as the number of rows in data_dC (which is also the length of x). Do you mean for you the length is only 2?

Comment: It seems that way yes, I have two data points: one below the demarcation line and one above...?

Comment: What if you print x, before the call to myBoundary? What is the length of x?

Comment: Well it is working for me (length returned by myBoundary is the same as the length of x), so I can suggest to print x before and after the line: x = np.array([float(x0) for x0 in x]). Maybe the float() conversion does not behave as expected with your text input.